# ComboBoxItem highlight color Windows8

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-8, combobox, controltemplate

I have this code to set the background of the `ComboBoxItem` with mouseover.

```
<ComboBox.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"     Color="Orange"/>
        </ComboBox.Resources>
        <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Orange" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

It's ok in Win Vista, Win 7, but not on Win8. I read that they changed the framework in aero, and I have to use controltemplate for it. How to make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but Triggers are not supported in windows 8 RT xaml..the code you have uploaded is must be of Wpf xaml..and you can change the comboboxitem style like below

```
   <ComboBox Height="20" Width="200">
        <ComboBox.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OrangeColor" Color="Orange"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OpacityOrangeColor" Color="Orange" Opacity="0.5"/>
        </ComboBox.Resources>
        <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                            <Grid>
                                <Border x:Name="Border" Background="Transparent"/>
                                <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="ComboBoxItem.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource OrangeColor}" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource OpacityOrangeColor}" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ComboBoxItem>xcvxvxc</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>sdfdsfsd</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

and there is no need of storing color in resources of combobox..you can directly apply colors to background and borderbrush. i have saved in resources because you saved in resources

Comment: You said *Triggers are not supported in windows 8 xaml*. Let's be clear about this because that is incorrect... Triggers are only not supported in Windows 8 RT.

Comment: Thanks for updating... I didn't think there would be any need to down vote on this occasion.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it yet, but I believe that in Window 8, you can fulfil your requirement by simply overriding this new `Brush` as you did with the old `SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey` one:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Orange" />
```

It also depends whether you're using the dark or light theme, but you can find a complete list of these new `Brush`es in the [ComboBoxItem styles and templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj709911.aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: I just simply have to add to it?

<ComboBox.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Orange"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Orange" />
            </ComboBox.Resources>

Comment: Did it not work? You know, I've just had a good search on this subject and there is surprisingly little information on this. These new `Brush`es are declared with the new [`ThemeResource` markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263118.aspx) and this linked page provides details about them, but no information on updating the values. Basically, the Windows 8.1 UI controls all use these `ThemeResource`s, so theoretically, if you define new `Brush`es with the same `x:Key` value in a local scope, then any UI control using that resource should use the new value too.

Comment: People that down vote without leaving a comment are foolish in my opinion... it is pointless doing that because they are making no point. Care to explain your down vote mystery down voter?